# How to move multiple meshes to the world origin at the same time?

Tags: objects, transforms, world, origin

I have about 50 meshes in my blender scene and I want all of them moved to the world origin. I can do this for each single mesh by going into the world and editing the transform. (See picture)

[image: Editing transform of object]

However, this does not work when having multiple objects selected.

Also, I have not found another way to do it that would work with multiple objects.

So my question is, how do you get all the meshes to the world origin without doing it for each one manually?

Comment: select all then hit alt+g

Comment: That worked, thanks!